# Error injecting: org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.Deploy

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss, continuous-deployment

I am getting the following error while building my maven project.

```
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ project-parent ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.Deploy
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/as/controller/client/ModelControllerClient
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:1914)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:1914)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] project-parent .................................... FAILURE [  0.426 s]
[INFO] project-ejb ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] project-web ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] project-ear ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.899 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-15T15:30:21+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project project-parent: Execution default-cli of goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:deploy: org/jboss/as/controller/client/ModelControllerClient
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/jboss/as/plugins/jboss-as-maven-plugin/7.9.Final/jboss-as-maven-plugin-7.9.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

The structure of my project is

```
project-parent
    -pom.xml
    -project-ear
        -pom.xml    
    -project-ejb
        -pom.xml
    -project-web
        -pom.xml
```

I am using private repository to fetch all the relevant jars for my project.

I have already tried deleting ~/.m2/repository folder but no luck. I have verified that there are no corrupt jars in my local repository plus this used to run fine till few weeks back and just started throwing this error.

For some strange reason, it now tries to download `plexus-utils-1.1.jar` after downloading `jboss-as-maven-plugin-7.9.Final.jar`. This `plexus-utils-1.1.jar` seems to require that `ModelControllerClient` class. I have another server setup few weeks back where the same code runs perfectly fine and it never downloads plexus-utils-1.1.jar. So not sure what is wrong in my current setup.

How could I resolve this issue?

---

**EDIT**

Adding parent pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>project-repo</id>
            <name>project custom repo</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/my/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>   
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.9.Final</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>${hostname}</hostname>
                        <port>9999</port>
                        <username>${jbossuser}</username>
                        <password>${jbosspassword}</password>
                    </configuration>                 
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>     
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>ear</module>
        <module>ejb</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: JBoss AS7 Deployment Plugin, Why?

Comment: @FedericoSierra Cause I have to deploy my app on an older version of JBoss (JBoss EAP 6.1) through maven. That's why

Comment: Ok. Can you post your parent pom? specifically the `jboss-as-maven-plugin` configuration.

Comment: @FedericoSierra done

Comment: Seems `jboss-as-controller-client:7.2.0.Final` is missing, check your local repository has access to this dependency

Comment: It is there on local repo. I verified it earlier. Also, I tried deleting it in my .m2 folder and it re-downloaded from my local repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after going to and fro with what could have possibly gone wrong, I focused my efforts on my private repository. As mentioned in the question, the first step was to verify if there are any corrupt files within my .m2 folder or in my private repo and found there were no corrupt jar files.

Next, I removed jboss-as-maven-plugin folder from within my .m2 folder as this plugin was related to the error. I also removed this artifact from my private repo and tried running my setup again.

This time as the artifact was no longer available on my private repo; it downloaded it from the maven central repo and it proceeded to download other related jar files which this plugin might have required and this time the setup worked fine. This would have worked fine with the private repo if I knew about the other related jars and had them in my private repo.

Regarding why it was working on one of my other servers, on that particular server when I ran the maven deploy command initially then I didn't had the jboss-as-maven-plugin artifact in my private repo so on that server it downloaded all the relevant jar files from maven central repo and it has been using those files ever since from its .m2 folder